# Use of median rather than individual data

Tags: regression, econometrics, median

I am running a linear regression model where the DV is income at closure from a program. One of the things I want to control for is median income in the county and county unemployment rates. So everyone in a county will have the same median income level and the same unemployment rate for these variables.

I have not found this discussed before remarkably, but I am sure it is not an ideal thing to do. I was hoping for suggestions on 1) is there a better way to control for these in linear regression and 2) what will the impact of having a predictor variable where many of the cases (individuals) will have the same value (they will all have the value for these two variables if they live in the same county).

Someone suggested I use multilevel models, I prefer linear regression if that is possible.

Comment: Why would you not prefer using multilevel models? Is there a specific reason regarding the analysis?

Comment: I have not worked with multilevel models for years and the amount of time it would take to catch up might be significant. I am far more familiar with linear models, I have only worked with multilevel models in class.

Comment: What are you worried about here? People control for age or years of education all the time, and having lots of people with the same age or years of schooling does not seem to stop them.

Comment: @T.E.G. Is spot on: your nation-level variables will (1) bias your variance/covariance estimates—something you might handle using, for example, a cluster variance estimator in a linear model, but (2) you may miss out on actual variation in intercepts and slopes/effects of your IVs (i.e. median income has a negative effect in these countries, effectively no effect in those countries, and a positive effect in the rest, extra problems if there are interactions with median income).

Comment: It is an experience thing. I have used linear regression a lot. ML models not for many years and only in class. I am not really worried about problems with variance. I have the entire population of interest (I know that is hard to believe, but I work for an agency that tracks all data for its customers and its only its customers that matter to it).  So p values are besides the point.  Thanks for the points, however.